# How to execute matlab function from Python and pass arguments to it?

Tags: python, matlab, subprocess

My test matlab function file is called hello_world.m and its code is:

```matlab
function [printed_line] = hello_world(name)
    str_to_display = strcat('Hello World from: ', string(name))
    disp(str_to_display)
    printed_line = strlength(name)
    return printed_line
```

I am currently trying to call it using the following lines:

```py
import subprocess
my_name = 'john wayne'
run_matlab = 'matlab -nodisplay -nojvm -nosplash -nodesktop -r "try, hello_world my_name, catch e, disp(getReport(e)), exit(1), end, exit(0);"'
subprocess.run(run_matlab, shell=True)
```

I would like to:

1. the result to be `Hello World from: john wayne` instead of `Hello world from: my_name`
2. get the returned variable of the function
3. possibly avoid the loading of matlab that happens when calling that command

Of course, I would like to call more complex functions, this is just a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: What is the command you use to run the matlab script from the command line? Without python I mean.

Comment: I don't know, I don't run it from the command line.

Comment: Well then try to do it. When you run the subprocess command you are reproducing what you would do in a shell, so first you want to understand what to run from the shell, then try to reproduce it in python.

Comment: @nonDucor for your suggested command, I changed it to `run_matlab = f"matlab -nodisplay -nojvm -nosplash -nodesktop -r \"hello_world('{my_name}'),exit(1), exit(0);\""` since it gave a few errors, even if now I have to manually close the matlab subprocess. Nice suggestion for part 2. For your suggestion for part 3, do I need to modify the previous command?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation? https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-matlab-functions-from-python.html

Comment: @nonDucor Please update your recommendation. `-r` is no longer recommended. It should be `matlab -batch "command"`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo in the past I had some troubles with `matlab.engine`, but following your tip I could try the solution in the documentation, as you mentioned. https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-user-script-and-function-from-python.html